# Dropbox SDK request error

Tags: swift, dropbox, swiftydropbox

I am using the `SwiftyDropbox SDK` and I am trying to upload an image file in my app but I keep getting the error:

> DropboxSDK: error making request to
>   /1/files_put/dropbox/MelanomaDiagnosis/6E3D4F7B-3342-44CA-B228-01919ED2DB19ExposureTimeVal16666000Scale1000000000.jpg - (400) v1_retired

Comment: Hi, this question will probably require the code that is causing the error. Maybe you are using an old API version?

Answer (score 0):

This `v1_retired` error indicates that you're calling Dropbox API v1, which is [retired](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/). (The `"/1/"` in the request URL also indicates that you're using API v1.)

[The SwiftyDropbox SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox) does not use API v1; it uses API v2, so it sounds like you actually are using a different SDK. Please follow [the instructions for SwiftyDropbox to install it](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#sdk-distribution).